# Google App Engine Java Datastore Query - Limit Results?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to fetch entries from the datastore and need to filter them by genre:

```jsp
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterPredicate"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.*"%>
```

```java
Query confQuery = new Query("Track");
Query.Filter topicFilter = new FilterPredicate("genre",
FilterOperator.EQUAL, genre);
confQuery.setFilter(topicFilter);
confQuery.addSort("lastplayed", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
PreparedQuery results = datastore.prepare(confQuery);
```

This will always return all of the entries with the given genre. How can I limit this to e.g. 10 entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use [FetchOptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions) like this

```
datastore.prepare(confQuery).asList(withLimit(10));
```

Comment: FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10)